# Show/Hide Application from/to System Tray

Tags: java, swt

I need some guidance in how to get the application to show up from the System Tray when I click on it.

I have managed to minimize the app on closure but I can't make it to show up.
If I'm builduing a new shell with same Contents would help?(I am building a SWT application)

This is how I am initializing my Shell: (I have modified it so I don't use AWT with SWT)

```
protected Shell shlSmartHouseSystem;

public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shlSmartHouseSystem.open();
    shlSmartHouseSystem.layout();
    while (!shlSmartHouseSystem.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my function where I am minimizing in Tray:

```
public void minimizeToTrayOnClose() {

        final Display display = shlSmartHouseSystem.getDisplay();
        Image image = new Image(display,"D:\\VIA_University_(Embedded_Systems)\\AJP_Workspace\\HouseSystem_Server\\icon-smart-house.png");
        Tray tray = display.getSystemTray();

    if (tray != null) {
        TrayItem trayItm = new TrayItem(tray,SWT.NONE);
        trayItm.setImage(image);

        final Menu menu = new Menu(shlSmartHouseSystem, SWT.POP_UP);

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
        menuItem.setText("Show");   
        menuItem.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {          
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                System.out.println("Opened");
            }
        });

        menuItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);        
        menuItem.setText("Exit");
        menuItem.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {          
            public void handleEvent (Event e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        trayItm.addListener (SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener () {
            public void handleEvent (Event event) {
                menu.setVisible (true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a mix of SWT and AWT/Swing here which is not good. You can use `Display.getSystemTray` or `Display.getSystemTaskBar` rather  than `SystemTray` to stick to just SWT.

Comment: I can change that to use to stick with SWT but I would still end up in the same situation.

Comment: I have changed it to use only SWT!!! And found how to actually make it work. Thank you for for the heads up with the mix!